# Adding custom scopes programmatically to Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm evaluating Azure B2C but can't work out whether it will be fit for the following scenario:

We have a single UI and and a single Web API. The API has two scopes defined: `read` and `write`.

The UI has two types of users: `standard` and `admin`. When a user logs in and gets an access token they both get a `read` scope but only an `admin` user should get `write`.

From what I've read Azure B2C doesn't support group based application, but is it possible to hook in to the token generation (e.g. a Function) and add a custom scope programmatically? I was thinking that if I can call a Function then this could check something to see if they should have the `write` scope added.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope o `scp` claims cannot be manipulated in B2C. However you can use [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started) and add (in a base policy) and output (in your relying party policy) a `roles` [claim type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#claimtype) so what your webapi do role base authorization ([.NET core sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1)). You can fill the `roles` values from the [output claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#outputclaims) provided by any technical profile which in turn relay on any configured Idp, AAD or even REST apis).